# Log in as a different user doesnt work in facebook sdk for .net in windows phone

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using facebook SDK for .NET to integrate facebook to windows phone application.
the facebook log in screen appears when I try to log in for the first time. Then if i sign out and sign in again the same user gets signed in.

My code is as follows:
for login

```
session = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,read_stream");
```

for logout

```
App.FacebookSessionClient.Logout();
```

How to log in as different user?

Comment: A bit more code would be helpful to solve your problem...

Comment: Basically i m using this example to get the code working its all the same http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/tutorial/ but i dont know how to sign in as a different user the above example works fine for me but i m not able to sign in as a different user

Comment: Try using a breakpoint on `App.FacebookSessionClient.Logout();` to see if it gets executed in your code

Comment: Did you click 'Save browser' when you logged in with the first user? How about clearing the browser control cache? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj571213%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the implementation of FacebookSessionClient.Logout() is not complete for now. Here is the code can do the trick for you:

```
    private void m_buttonLogout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        var logoutUrl = fb.GetLogoutUrl(new {
            next = "https://m.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html",
            access_token = App.FacebookSessionClient.CurrentSession.AccessToken;
        });

        var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.Navigated += (o, args) =>
       {
         if (args.Uri.AbsoluteUri == "https://m.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")
            {
            App.FacebookSessionClient.Logout();

            NavigationService.GoBack();
            }
        };

        webBrowser.Navigate(logoutUrl);
    }//private void m_buttonLogout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```